# Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I wrote a simple PHP code to connect to the MySQL server as below

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "Kepwd";
$hostname = "localhost:81";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
```

but this generates the following errors. I found some topics regarding this issue in google and Stack Overflow. but those don't help me.

```
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\SSDConsultingNew\inc\test.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0014  240936  {main}( )   ..\test.php:0
2   0.0014  241528  mysqli_connect ( )  ..\test.php:8

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=10612 in C:\wamp\www\SSDConsultingNew\inc\test.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0014  240936  {main}( )   ..\test.php:0
2   0.0014  241528  mysqli_connect ( )  ..\test.php:8

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\SSDConsultingNew\inc\test.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0014  240936  {main}( )   ..\test.php:0
2   0.0014  241528  mysqli_connect ( )  ..\test.php:8
Unable to connect to MySQL
```

Comment: Your subject line reads as "Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away" which contains a `mysql_` function, as opposed to the rest of what's in your question, being `mysqli_` functions. Is that the actual error you're getting?

Comment: yes. I use mysqli_ function

Comment: Look at this `mysql_connect()` that is what you originally posted as part of the subject line, not `mysqli_connect()`, therefore you can disregard my first comment.

Comment: Try it without the port `$hostname = "localhost";` - You may also have another application using that same port. If so, you will need to find out what it is, or try port 3306

Comment: @Fred-ii- it works without port. but I can't understand why. I have changed the port :80 to :81 in apache server because it conflict with IIS server

Comment: I won't be able to help you there. I know nothing about that type of server.

Comment: anyway thank you so much. IIS server comes with visual studio

Comment: You're confusing the IIS web server and the mysql server. What would you need to connect to your localhost over your external IIS port to connect to the mysql server for? Your MySQL port is running on default 3306, when you remove `localhost:81` it can resolve the address.

Comment: Super old question, but I just had this issue and it wasn't because of any of the above mentioned things. I used MySQL Workbench to create a user, and I selected SHA-256 as the password instead of standard...that caused this error to get thrown when trying to connect to the DB. Maybe someone can find this comment useful, as it took me 4 hours to figure out. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AndrewQuebe Thank you! I banged my head against this for hours until I found your comment. I had to go back and reconfigure MySQL 8 Community Edition to even allow "standard" passwords but doing so did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

The error is here:

```
$hostname = "localhost:81";
```

You are not connecting to MySQL, but to Apache server. If you didn't change MySQL port just use

```
$hostname = "localhost";
```

Comment: Yeah, we've established that in comments already. Ohgodwhy's comment makes sense to me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yup. And also port must be specified as a separate parameter to mysqi_connect, not together with host.

Comment: Yep, that too. `$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);` as per http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**you forget to specify the database name after entering database name try again. The syntax should be like this**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Wrong. Database name is optional.